How do Istio Gateway ,VirtualService ,DestinationRule works together to fullfill a request?
I have a app running on k8s with istio as service mesh and nginx as ingress controller. I wonder what would be the request flow to my service. Is it possibly like so:
user-request -->istio_gateway --> istio_virtualServive --> istio_destinationRoute --> nginx_ingress --> service_pod .

Any suggestions / insights?

I would recommend to remove Nginx Ingress from the equation. Although it's possible to use Nginx Ingress with Istio, it makes zero sense to do that since it adds an unnecessary hop and extra logic which will be difficult to troubleshoot. Istio is more than enough to deliver traffic to your app.
Other than that your traffic diagram looks valid.
